# Paypal payment and Product activation

Tags: php, paypal, authentication

**Scenario:**

- I have built a customized website using PHP and MySQL(without using opensource CMS) for users to take up online quiz.
- I have set up a registration page for users to register and login.
- Once, they login, user will be able to navigate to a 'Buy packages' where the user will be able to purchase quiz packages. Eg. Package 1, Package 2, Package 3 & Package 4. Only after they make payment, they will be able to access the quizzes.
- I am using Paypal integrated to receive payments.

**Issue**

- I have currently 4 packages priced individually.
- I have created 4 paypal payment buttons for each package so that the user can buy the desired package.
- Once the payment is made, the user should be automatically provide access to the package he has purchased.

For eg. user has purchased package 1. Once the payment is successful, he will be having access to take tests that are in package 1.

What do I need to implement this? How do I do it?
I have some idea regarding IPN paypal. However I would like to know how can this be done?

Thank you
Hareesh

Answer (score 0):

You need to get some verification from paypal, that the payment is done. If so, store an information about which package was bought by the user in your database and check if they bought the package when they request it. I would recommand to store the information in the *$SESSION* variable on logon too, to avoid unnessescarry database calls.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Let me test it and get back to you!